# Whose grave do they find at the end of The Curse of the Blue Figurine?

Tags: john-bellairs

As the end of the young adult horror novel, *The Curse of the Blue Figurine* by John Bellairs, the protagonist Johnny Dixon and his older adult friend Professor Childermass confront the ghost of Father Bart in a clearing part way up a mountain, beneath a rock formation called "The Hag."

The ghost is finally defeated by locating a grave on the site.  They disinter some mortal remains and use them against the villainous spirit.  The ghost says something about that place being where he has the most power, which suggests that it might be his own grave.  However, Professor Childermass goes on about how major prophets (such as Moses) might be spirited away before death and buried by angels.

I have read this book many time since I was in elementary school, and I *always* felt like a I was missing some crucial clue about whose grave they found located there.  Is there something I missed, or is the identity of the person laid to rest there just an unresolved enigma?